# Powershell, start or stop iis site using msdeploy

Tags: powershell, msdeploy, iis-8.5

I was trying to migrate my batch script to powershell.

I have tried writing the script and run it from powershell ise.

```
$sites = @("abc","xyz","pqr")
foreach ($site in $sites)
{
    msdeploy -verb:sync -verbose -source:runcommand -dest:runcommand="$env:windir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd stop site /site.name":$site
}
```

When I run the command(msdeploy) it runs perfect from command prompt.

I get the following error (attached):

[Error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6J9N.png)

I would appreciate if someone can help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much of struggle I figured it out, and resolved the issue.

```
foreach($site in $sites){
msdeploy -verb:sync -verbose -source:runcommand -dest:runcommand=`"$env:windir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd stop site /site.name`":"$site",computername="$serverName",username="$user",password="$passCode"
}
```

It was just a escape character that helped me to run the script("`").

I hope it helps someone without pulling their hair.

Comment: How do you start IIS again?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Invoke-Expression` which will allow you to execute a string as a command. Store your command as a string and pass it to `Invoke-Expression` as a parameter.

```
$sites = @("abc","xyz","pqr")
$commandPrefix = 'msdeploy -verb:sync -verbose -source:runcommand -dest:runcommand="$env:windir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd stop site /site.name"'
foreach ($site in $sites)
{
    $command = $commandPrefix ":" $site
    Invoke-Expression $command
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have posted my solution below.

Comment: Yes, I was able to run the command after using the escape character.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the recycleApp provider:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="MySite",recycleMode="StopAppPool"
//deploy and sync content
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="MySite",recycleMode="StartAppPool"
```

Comment: Thanks Alan for letting me know to use msdeploy's recycleApp.